# Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ - Partitioning using header instead of routing key

Tags: rabbitmq, partitioning, spring-cloud-stream

I was going through the documentation but couldn't find anything related to this, so I'm here just to confirm with you.

We'd like to partition Rabbit queues using Spring Cloud Stream, but would like to do so without using routing keys for it. Is there a way to do it by using headers or properties in the messages?

RabbitMQ plugins allow this but, does spring cloud stream allow it in some way?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually provision whatever exchange type you want and set the `declareExchange` property to `false`.